# CRM 2013- Pass all records id selected in view on click of button

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, ribbon

I will be having one command bar button on contacts HomePage Grid and Sub grid.

On click of that button i want to pass all records id being shown in view. So consider advance find find view also.

**We can pass selectedcontolitemids to JS. I don't want this.**

on click of that button the id's should be passed to JavaScript.

**NOTE: user will not select any record. they will just click button.**

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is not a recommended way, I hope this is what you are looking for. Please find this blog.

[CRM 2011 – Javascript and Subgrids code example](http://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2011/05/19/crm-2011-javascript-and-subgrids-code-example/)

Comment: I don't mean to say Sub Grid on form. When we do ribbon customization we have HomepPageGrid,SubGrid and form.

Comment: In those cases also this approach should work. Did you try this?

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I have tried this.. It returns the 50 records shown in the grid. I want all records shown. Suppose for one particular view there are 200 records but first page shows 50.. I want all 200 records. In CRM 4.0 we used to get XML of grid control using document.all['crmGrid'].gridXml... How can we get GridXml in CRM 2013? i am able to find gridControl using document.getElementById('crmGrid').control but no xml.